# insert multiple comulns from sparksql to hbase

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with ***n parameter of columns more than 100*** and i want to insert them to hbase.
What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

HBase connector can be used, more details here:
https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc

Comment: i'm using spark 1.3